# basic bouncing ball in graphics window

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to create a simple animation that bounces a GOval ball off the bottom and top of the graphics window, up and down again and again until I exit the window. The problem is I don't understand how to get the ball to recognize the bottom of the graphics window and start to bounce the other way. In other words, the ball never bounces off the floor, it just keeps falling and eventually disappears off the bottom of the screen. 
 Is it the correct approach to thinking about this problem that as long as i < STEPS that the ball should move down. I don't understand what the condition should be for the ball to bounce up, and then down again.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class BouncingBall extends GraphicsWindow{
    public void run(){
        GOval ball = new GOval(0, 0, OVAL_SIZE, OVAL_SIZE);
        ball.setFilled(true);
        add(ball);

        int dx = 0;
        int dy = 1;

        while(true) {
            int i = 0;
            if ( i < STEPS) {
                ball.move(dx, dy);
                pause(PAUSE_TIME);
            } 
            if (??) {
                ball.move(dx, - dy);
                pause(PAUSE_TIME);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private static final STEPS = 1000; 
    private static final OVAL_SIZE = 25; 
    private static final PAUSE_TIME = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `GraphicsProgram` instead of `GraphicsWindow`?

`GraphicsProgram`s have a `getHeight()` method that will tell you how tall your window is. So in this case:

```
if (ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() >= getHeight()) {
    dy = -dy;
}
```

This will reverse the y-velocity of the ball when it goes past the bottom of the screen. You can write similar code for the top of the screen if you want it to bounce back and forth.

Comment: Alright, then try using that condition for your code and flip the velocity and see if it works.

Comment: I'm having lots of trouble with this problem. Your code words to bounce the ball once off floor but it does not bounce off the ceiling again. I'm trying to continually bounce the ball back and forth over and over off the ceiling and floor.

Answer (score 0):

The basic algorithm here is to use the size of the display area and the size of the bounds on your object to determine when the object is colliding with the edge of the display area. When this occurs, negate the appropriate element of your velocity vector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the direction in a boolean like this:

```
  boolean up=true;
  while(true){

  if (up){
  ball.move(dx, dy);
  pause(PAUSE_TIME);
  } 
  else
  {
  ball.move(dx, - dy);
  pause(PAUSE_TIME);
  }
  if(getHeight()<=ball.getHeight+ball.getY()||ball.getHeight()<=ball.getY){
  up=!up;      
  }
  }
```

Now if the ball reaches the end of the window, it changes its direction and moves in the opposite direction.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to make a boolean for this. Negating the y-velocity (dy = -dy) works well too, and requires a little less code.